# In NextJS how to pass data from server.js to _app.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

In my NextJS project, I'm using `koa` as the web framework in `server.js` file, what I want to do is as follows,

1. Do some external api calls to generate some custom data in `server.js` per each request,
2. Then pass the generated data to `_app.js`, so that the data could be shared by all pages via props or contexts.

My question is how could we pass the data generated in `server.js` to `_app.js` or pages?

Here are some code examples,

```js
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
// server.js
import Koa from "koa";
import Router from "koa-router";

const verified_names = {};
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();  // NextJS use this to handle each request

app.prepare().then(async () => {
  const server = new Koa();
  const router = new Router();
  ...

  // in verifyNameFunc, if name is verified, will set verified_names[name] = some_data
  router.get("/verify_name", verifyNameFunc);

  router.get("(.*)", async (ctx) => {
    // custom logic starts here: if name is not verified, redirect to /verify_name
    const name = ctx.query.name;
    if (verified_names[name] === undefined) {
        ctx.redirect(`/verify_name?name=${name}`);
    }
    // HERE: do some external api calls and generate some data
    var custom_data = custom_logic(verified_names[name]);

    // I think here starts rendering the pages (i.e. enters the execution of `_app.js` and pages)
    // QUESTION: how to pass the above `custom_data` to _app.js or pages?
    await handle(ctx.req, ctx.res);  
    }
  });

  server.use(router.routes());
  server.listen(...);
  
});

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
// _app.js

class MyApp extends App {
  ...
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ ctx }) => {
  // Can we get the `custom_data` from server.js here?
  ...
};
```

The reason why I want to keep the `custom_logic` inside `server.js` is that,

- If `name` is not verified, a redirect would happen and `verifyNameFunc` will set some data into `verified_names`.

I'm not sure if this redirect could be moved into `_app.js` as well?

Comment: Why not move the `custom_logic` that retrieves the data directly to `MyApp.getInitialProps`? Do you actually need to do it in the custom server?

Comment: @juliomalves Great question, let me update the post right away to show why!

Comment: @juliomalves Updated, basically it's because there would be some redirects happening to generate the custom data, I'm not sure if it can be moved into `_app.js`.

Comment: Yes, it could be moved there even with redirects. The exact same code could be used in `getInitialProps`.

Comment: @juliomalves Awesome! BTW, I really wonder that if I still would like to keep the custom logic inside `server.js`, can we somehow pass the `custom_data` into `_app.js`?

Comment: You could pass the data through the `res` object, for instance. But I would not recommend it, as [that's not the intended usage for the custom server in Next.js](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/5139#issuecomment-420204979).

Comment: @juliomalves I see, thanks. However I'm worried that I move the custom logic into `_app.js`, then the global var `verified_names` would also need to be moved into `_app.js` and so on, that would make my `_app.js` code more complicated, also making `server.js` not doing its part of job.

Comment: Then maybe you don't need the custom server at all? And should move all the logic to `_app` instead.

Comment: @juliomalves Thanks for your valuable input, I'll carefully consider my code again!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getInitialProps` and do the redirect in `__app.tsx` if you need to.

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps

Also it's rather easy to check if a name is verified in `__app.tsx` and then to render a different child based on that.  I don't think you need an entire custom server for that.

Also take a look at https://nextjs.org/blog/next-10-2#routing-based-on-headers-and-query-string-parameters.

Answer (score 1):

It's just one of solutions:
Create a separate js file (module), where you will export two functions `setData()` and `getData()` like this:

```js
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
// ./lib/data-manager.js

let promiseResolver = undefined;
const promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
  promiseResolver = resolve;
})

export function setData(data) { promiseResolver(data); }
export function async getData() { return promise; }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
// server.js
import { setData } from "../lib/data-manager"
import Koa from "koa";
import Router from "koa-router";

const verified_names = {};
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();  // NextJS use this to handle each request

app.prepare().then(async () => {
  const server = new Koa();
  const router = new Router();
  ...

  // in verifyNameFunc, if name is verified, will set verified_names[name] = some_data
  router.get("/verify_name", verifyNameFunc);

  router.get("(.*)", async (ctx) => {
    // custom logic starts here: if name is not verified, redirect to /verify_name
    const name = ctx.query.name;
    if (verified_names[name] === undefined) {
        ctx.redirect(`/verify_name?name=${name}`);
    }
    // HERE: do some external api calls and generate some data
    var custom_data = custom_logic(verified_names[name]);

    setData(custom_data); // <-- saving data

    // I think here starts rendering the pages (i.e. enters the execution of `_app.js` and pages)
    // QUESTION: how to pass the above `custom_data` to _app.js or pages?
    await handle(ctx.req, ctx.res);  
    }
  });

  server.use(router.routes());
  server.listen(...);
  
});

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
// _app.js
import { getData } from "../lib/data-manager"

class MyApp extends App {
  ...
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ ctx }) => {
  const custom_data = await getData();  // <-- getting data
};
```

Keep in mind that `getInitialProps` enables server-side rendering in a page and allows you to do initial data population, it means sending the page with the data already populated from the server (See https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps).
But, as it was recommended to you, maybe you don't need custom server at all

Comment: I think I'm confused by whether if I need custom server or not. My understanding is, the next.js has a built-in server, but it's primarily for ssr rendering, and for more advanced web server functionalities, we still need to use things like `koa`, no?

Comment: Thanks for your code! One quick question, `setData` and `getData` would access the data, and the data can be seen as a global var? Or data is stored in external db?

Comment: Neither in a global var, nor in external db. `setData` will actually put the value of `custom_data` to the internal value of the Promise that in turn is used in a normal js module. In my solution I've used two concepts: [modules](https://javascript.info/modules-intro) and [promises](https://javascript.info/promise-basics). I hope my answer will help you and you will accept it

Comment: About `koa`: I'm not familiar with it, so I can't say for sure. But if it's just another server, then yes, you probably could rework your code to get rid of it. That would be better for sure, because without custom server you'll get some additional optimizations from 'Next.js' framework itself (see https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server)

Comment: I see, thanks for your comments